# I dont connect ESP8266 Acces Point

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I am using ESP8266 and programming it with Lua. I want to use ESP8266 access point but i dont need to connect internet. I am tuning in this module Access point with at below command. When i want to connect the ESP8266, the connection is perpetual refreshing and i got an error like 'you cant connect the internet with this AP' . Due to that connection is perpetual refreshing but i dont have to connect internet i only need connect a server in the ESP8266. For example when i adjusted to ESP8266 to be AP ,it get an IP address 192.168.4.1 and after when i created a server in this ESP, i am connecting this server through 192.168.4.1. But i have to connect ESP8266 access point. Due to the problem i mentioned above, that is not happening. How can i fix it?

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.SOFTAP);
cfg={};
-- Set the SSID of the module in AP mode and access password
cfg.ssid="ESP8266-SmartPlug";
cfg.pwd="password";
```

Comment: "i have to connect ESP8266 access point" - what does that mean? Do you need Station + AP mode, where the ESP8266 both creates its own network while at the same time being joined to another existing network?

Comment: I created a TCP server in ESP8266. To access this Server , I have to join same network with ESP8266. I opened wifi in my phone and ı saw 'ESP8266-SmartPlug' and i entered the password and i connected. But about after 10 ms the connection is refreshing and due to that i cannot reach server.

Comment: "To access this Server , I have to join same network with ESP8266" - that's not correct. The client who wants to access that server just needs to be in the same network as the server. You can also achieve that if the ESP8266 is in _station mode_ and connects to the same access point as your client.

Comment: Mr Marcel Stör i cant use extra Access Point. I have to use ESP8266 as access point and server. Also to use computer i can connect ESP8266 access point, but android phone is refreshing connection perpetual and IOS phones are never connecting i tried half an hour ago. If available could you write your ESP8266 code above and test it your phone and computer? You can see what i mean more clearly.